# C# Timeout in windows service when using entity framework and sending up to 500 emails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-services

I have a windows service that runs every 5 minutes to send out emails. One go can send out a maximum of maybe 500 emails. Just recently we moved over to Gmail to send emails and this has cause the service to repeatedly (several times per hour) cast the following message:

*"The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding"*

In the background there is a timer that kicks in every 5 minutes to send all piled up emails. When triggered it then stops the timer, fetches the emails using Entity Framework 6, loops through and sends all of them and finally starts the timer again.

```
private void FetchAndSendEmails(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
{
    _serverTimer.Stop();

    try 
    {
        var db = new MainServerContext();
        var emailsToSend = db.Mails
                           .Where(x => x.IsSent.Equals(false) && x.IsDeleted.Equals(false))
                           .OrderBy(x => x.Priority)
                           .ThenBy(x => x.EntryCreated)
                           .Take(_maxEmailsToSendPerExecution)
                           .Select(x => new MailItem() { Id = x.MailId, Recipient = x.Recipient }) }).ToList(); // Fetches a lot more fields here

        for (int i = 0; i < emailsToSend.Count(); i++)
        {
            var dbEmail = emailsToSend[i];
            SendEmail(0, dbEmail, ref db);
            continue;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log error                
    }
    finally
    {
        _serverTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

SendEmail method

```
var mailClient = new SmtpClient();            
mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
mailClient.Host = _host; // smtp.gmail.com
mailClient.Port = _port; // 465
mailClient.EnableSsl = _useSSL;
mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mailerItem.Username, mailerItem.Password);
mailClient.Timeout = 20000;

//add recipient, body, attachments etc.

mailClient.Send(message);

// Update mail sent
var item = db.Mails.First(x => x.MailId.Equals(mail.Id));
item.IsSent = true;
item.Sent = DateTime.Now;
item.FromEmail = mailerItem.FromEmailAddress;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Should i maybe go over to use async? Declare EF differently? Change some Gmail settings?

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the error occurring, fetching the mail items or marking them as sent?  I'm a bit concerned about `// fetches a lot more fields here` because you are loading all your emails into memory using `.ToList()` instead of iterating over the EF query results.

Comment: Where is the error actually occurring? Seems to be a SqlServer exception which indicates that the EF query seems to be timing out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with Gmail, their mail servers are very protected on which applications send out emails. Also make sure you do not have 2 step verification on that account.

I switched to SMTP2Go(smtp2go.com) and I am able to send out as many emails without issue.

Below is a snippet of code I used to send out mass emails: http://pastie.org/10876521

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the code waits for FetchAndSendEmails() to finish, even if it takes longer than 5 minutes.

Load and process the emails 1 at a time, rather than in batches of 500.

Dispose the DbContext after use.

```
  using (var db = new MainServerContext())
  {
     ...
  }
```

It could be stuck on one email. Keep records of how many times each email has been attempted, and send them in rotation.

Make sure that there is no [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) in force when calling FetchAndSendEmails(), because there is hard-coded maximum time limit of 10 minutes for a transaction - and no practical way of extending that limit (transactions are supposed to be short-lived). If that limit were exceeded, you would get an exception.